# Create portfolio backed skill-set in django ORM

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a specialized `User` class that inherits from `django.contrib.auth.models.User`. Now, this `User` class will have tags associated with it, for example: <kbd>Blogger</kbd>, <kbd>French Cuisine Cook</kbd>, <kbd>Python Programmer</kbd>.

Ideally, what I want to do, is have each of these traits backed up by something that they have done, ideally a `PortfolioItem`. So, a `User` will have a set of tags, and these tags, and the relationship with each of these tags is going to be understood through these `PortfolioItem`s. How would one achieve something like this using the django ORM?

Please note, that the tags are generic, however, the portfolios behind each of these tags are unique to every user.

How would one go about doing, this using the `through` variable in django ORMs.

### UPDATE

I've tried simple adding `PortfolioItem` as the `through` variable, but in that case you will need to create a unique tag each time you want to add a list of portfolio item. The thing is I want tags to be generic.

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: For maximum flexibility, I'd say you want a `PortfolioItem` model with a many-to-one relationship to `User`, a `Tag` model, then a mapping table to create a many-to-many relationship between `Tag`s and `PortfolioItem`s.  If you want to make it optional to have a tag associated with a portfolio item, put a link from the mapping table to `User` as well, and make the `PortfolioItem` link nullable.

Comment: @SimeonVisser I've tried simple adding `PortfolioItem` as the `through` variable, but in that case you will need to create a unique tag each time you want to add a list of portfolio item. The thing is I want tags to be generic.

Comment: The docs don't read like you need a unique tag for each.  In fact, that would kind of defeat the purpose.  You should be able to provide a tag instance you looked up from the DB as easily as a newly created one.